# How do I add icons to buttons in pug?

Tags: pug

I am trying to add a icon to a button element, after doing some googling I found that doing works:

```
<button onlick='window.location.href="/"'>
  <img src="/assets/icon.png">
</button>
```

How do I do this in pug? When I try to do something like this it gives me errors.

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gINkF.png)

Comment: Please show the full error.

Comment: @MatiasKinnunen https://imgur.com/a/25XJJiu